# Align tcolorbox in center vertically using overlay

Tags: overlays

In first slide, tcolorbox is aligned vertically center. But in second slide, unable to align the tcolorbox properly.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,landscape,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=128mm,
            paperheight=96mm,
            margin=8mm,
            footskip=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{overlays}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\phantom{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\textbf{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\clearpage
~
\vfill
\begin{overlays}{2}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\only{1}{
The grass \texthide{is} green
}
\only{2}{
The grass \textshow{is} green
}
\end{tcolorbox}
%
\vfill
~
\end{overlays}
\vfill
~
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```tex
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,landscape,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=128mm,
            paperheight=96mm,
            margin=8mm,
            footskip=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{overlays}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\phantom{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\textbf{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{overlays}{2}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[before=\leavevmode\vskip-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip\relax\vfill\par, after=\par\vfill]
  \only{1}{
  The grass \texthide{is} green
  }
  \only{2}{
  The grass \textshow{is} green
  }
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{overlays}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you want the `tcolorbox` env to be exactly vertically centered at the text area of current page, use `tcolorbox` option `box align=center`. OP's setting makes the center of text area and center of the whole page overlap, which is more or less a coisidence.

```tex
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,landscape,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[paperwidth=128mm,
            paperheight=96mm,
            margin=8mm,
            footskip=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{overlays}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\phantom{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{\hspace*{3mm}\textbf{#1}\hspace*{3mm}}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\lohead{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
    \draw
      (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west)
      (current page.north west) -- (current page.south east);
    \draw[purple]
      (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.south west)
      (current page text area.north west) -- (current page text area.south east);
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{overlays}{2}  
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    before=\leavevmode\vskip-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topskip\relax\vfill\par,
    after=\par\vfill,
    box align=center,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    opacityback=0.5,
    overlay={
      \draw[blue]
        (frame.north east) -- (frame.south west)
        (frame.north west) -- (frame.south east);
    }
  ]
    \only{1}{
      The grass \texthide{is} green
    }
    \only{2}{
      The grass \textshow{is} green
    }
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{overlays}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have a question: Is the \relax and two \par mandatory here?

Comment: @Tom Looks like neither of them is mandatory. `\relax` is for `\dimexpr` to stop, two `\par`s are for ensuring the `tcolorbox` env is on its own paragraph.

Comment: I just add a answer to illustrate something according to your answer. Correct me if there are something wrong in it.

Comment: @Tom See answer update. I added a revised example using `box align=center`, with crosses showing centers of the tcolorbox env, the text area, and the whole page.

Comment: This is great! There is empty line in the second code between tikz and tcolorbox, which shift down the tcolorbox env. Please delete it.

Comment: @Tom It doesn't matter. That empty line is converted to a `\par` so tex enters vertical mode. But vertical mode is just what we want before `tcolorbox` env.

Comment: Are you sure? When I copy and compile it. The tcolorbox was off center.

Comment: @Tom Sorry, you're right. I moved the overlaid cross-drawing `\tikz` into header. Now it should be more robust.